# Is Python Capable of Creating Thousands of Unique Renders with Similar Subject?

Tags: python, scripting

Programming Question

I've been using Blender for several years now but I have little to no experience in programming python. I'm managing a project to create 10,000 unique images with a similar base between all. The images will feature a similar subject such as a robot but each image will feature different props such as hats, body color, background etc...

There will be 5 sets of props, each containing 10 unique units. For example 10 unique hats, 10 unique backgrounds etc...

I'm asking for advise from experienced scripters if there's a way to create a program to do the following:

Automatically display 1 prop from each set in an instance, render and save the image (eevee would be fine), display a new permutation, render & save, and repeat to create 10,000 unique images (thus without repeating any combination of props from the sets).

Comment: Short answer is, Yes.

Comment: 10^5 is 100,000, not 10,000 fyi :) you might be interested in the python `itertools` module for figuring out the permutations

Comment: Appreciate it haha. This is why I'm not the dev lol. I appreciate any and all tips.

Comment: Agree with batFINGER. Recommend edit your question and add any real world example to test, ideally a blend.

Comment: Not only is it possible, I dare to say it's easy, and with low output resolution and sample size ("Eevee would be fine") the script probably can do all the work in a single day (for 10 000 renders) or a week (for 100 000 renders)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help. But....

I am writing a tool where I read info from a .csv file. Then I use that info to create geometry. As part of the creation stage, I create a collection for everything that I want to render.

Then I create a render layer for each collection, and I automate the activation/deactivation of each collection for each render layer.

This gives me a bunch of render layers, that I can then render out using F12.

Your question isn't specific enough, but I'm fairly sure you can do what you want to do. But you'll most likely have to load *everything* you need into the scene, and then activate/deactivate whatever you need to render at any given time.